# How to log spring data generated solr query on console or in a file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-solr

How to log spring data generated solr query on console or in a file. I am using spring-data-solr version 2.0.6.RELEASE from spring boot version 1.4.3.RELEASE.

I am trying to log statements in file or console as we are able to do this in spring-data-jpa for sql statements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SolrTemplate` logs the created query string when executing the query. Enable logging eg. in `logback.xml` by adding

```xml
<logger name="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Which should give you something like:

```sh
2017-10-17 08:09:45,451 DEBUG o.s.d.solr.core.SolrTemplate: 504 - Executing query 'q={!join+from%3Dmanu_id_s+to%3Did}text:ipod' against solr.
2017-10-17 08:09:46,148 DEBUG o.s.d.solr.core.SolrTemplate: 504 - Executing query 'q=*:*&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=5&facet.field=name&facet.field=cat&facet.prefix=lan&f.name.facet.prefix=spr' against solr.
```

In case you're missing information in the logs please feel free to open an enhancement request in the [bug tracker](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR/).

Comment: It worked!!! thank you @Christoph Strobl. Now I am able to see the query request in log file.

Comment: For those who come from search: you can simply use `query.toString()` to print the actual query. It will prepare and print the string that could be used along with Solr admin(admin query url + string). To chech implementation take a look at `SolrParams.query(` method in sources